# Quickly read the last line of a text file?

Tags: java, file, io

What's the quickest and most efficient way of reading the last line of text from a [very, very large] file in Java?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Have a look at my answer to a [similar question for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c). The code would be quite similar, although the encoding support is somewhat different in Java.

Basically it's not a terribly easy thing to do in general. As MSalter points out, UTF-8 does make it easy to spot `\r` or `\n` as the UTF-8 representation of those characters is just the same as ASCII, and those bytes won't occur in multi-byte character.

So basically, take a buffer of (say) 2K, and progressively read backwards (skip to 2K before you were before, read the next 2K) checking for a line termination. Then skip to exactly the right place in the stream, create an `InputStreamReader` on the top, and a `BufferedReader` on top of that. Then just call `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't matter - you need the last CR or LF character, which is a single byte in both ASCII and UTF-8.

Answer (score 96):

**Below are two functions, one that returns the last non-blank line of a file without loading or stepping through the entire file, and the other that returns the last N lines of the file without stepping through the entire file:**

What tail does is zoom straight to the last character of the file, then steps backward, character by character, recording what it sees until it finds a line break.  Once it finds a line break, it breaks out of the loop.  Reverses what was recorded and throws it into a string and returns.  0xA is the new line and 0xD is the carriage return.

If your line endings are `\r\n` or `crlf` or some other "double newline style newline", then you will have to specify n*2 lines to get the last n lines because it counts 2 lines for every line.

```
public String tail( File file ) {
    RandomAccessFile fileHandler = null;
    try {
        fileHandler = new RandomAccessFile( file, "r" );
        long fileLength = fileHandler.length() - 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(long filePointer = fileLength; filePointer != -1; filePointer--){
            fileHandler.seek( filePointer );
            int readByte = fileHandler.readByte();

            if( readByte == 0xA ) {
                if( filePointer == fileLength ) {
                    continue;
                }
                break;
                
            } else if( readByte == 0xD ) {
                if( filePointer == fileLength - 1 ) {
                    continue;
                }
                break;
            }

            sb.append( ( char ) readByte );
        }

        String lastLine = sb.reverse().toString();
        return lastLine;
    } catch( java.io.FileNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (fileHandler != null )
            try {
                fileHandler.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                /* ignore */
            }
    }
}
```

**But you probably don't want the last line, you want the last N lines, so use this instead:**

```
public String tail2( File file, int lines) {
    java.io.RandomAccessFile fileHandler = null;
    try {
        fileHandler = 
            new java.io.RandomAccessFile( file, "r" );
        long fileLength = fileHandler.length() - 1;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int line = 0;

        for(long filePointer = fileLength; filePointer != -1; filePointer--){
            fileHandler.seek( filePointer );
            int readByte = fileHandler.readByte();

             if( readByte == 0xA ) {
                if (filePointer < fileLength) {
                    line = line + 1;
                }
            } else if( readByte == 0xD ) {
                if (filePointer < fileLength-1) {
                    line = line + 1;
                }
            }
            if (line >= lines) {
                break;
            }
            sb.append( ( char ) readByte );
        }

        String lastLine = sb.reverse().toString();
        return lastLine;
    } catch( java.io.FileNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if (fileHandler != null )
            try {
                fileHandler.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
}
```

**Invoke the above methods like this:**

```
File file = new File("D:\\stuff\\huge.log");
System.out.println(tail(file));
System.out.println(tail2(file, 10));
```

**Warning**
In the wild west of unicode this code can cause the output of this function to come out wrong.  For example "Mary?s" instead of "Mary's".  Characters with [hats, accents, Chinese characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) etc may cause the output to be wrong because accents are added as modifiers after the character.  Reversing compound characters changes the nature of the identity of the character on reversal.  You will have to do full battery of tests on all languages you plan to use this with.

For more information about this unicode reversal problem read this:
https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/

Comment: The above does not take into account lines terminated with both CR and LF.

Comment: your multiline implementation does not work in your special cases of filePointer == fileLength, line will stay the same, therefore the condition line == lines will not fire after that and the code will read the whole file.

Comment: The warning about the wild west of Unicode is confession of a bug.  The algorithm utilized is flawed, hence the bug hence the warning.  In UTF8 there is a maximum length of multibyte encoding; that length is N=4B×max-length-of-combining-chars.  For any given byte position in a file, that byte might be a noninitial byte/grapheme in a nonnormalized Unicode character.  When the code above thinks that it has found a fact, it must deem it a suspicious fact until the prior N bytes are examined to determine whether the suspicious fact is in fact not a fact due to being within a UTF8 multibyte seq.

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER I confess to the bug, as you say, Next I would like you to analyze, and write a program to solve the global timezone-problem, as described by computerphile here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY

Comment: To avoid the Unicode problems related to reverting the string (or the StringBuilder), one can read to a byte list, from the end of the file, revert it to a byte array and then create the String from the byte array.

Answer (score 40):

Apache Commons has an implementation using [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

It's called [ReversedLinesFileReader](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html).

Comment: I think this is the quickest way to read file in reverse order

Comment: @JuanToroMarty It's possible to loop over the `readLine()` method.

Comment: This seems to me as the most elegant method.

Answer (score 6):

Using FileReader or FileInputStream won't work - you'll have to use either [FileChannel](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) or [RandomAccessFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) to loop through the file backwards from the end. Encodings will be a problem though, as Jon said.

Comment: Note, RandomAccessFile's performance sucks for individual operations - so do sensible size reads into a buffer.

Answer (score 4):

***You can easily change the below code to print the last line.***

**MemoryMappedFile for printing last 5 lines:**

```
private static void printByMemoryMappedFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        FileInputStream fileInputStream=new FileInputStream(file);
        FileChannel channel=fileInputStream.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer=channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size());
        buffer.position((int)channel.size());
        int count=0;
        StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
        for(long i=channel.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
            char c=(char)buffer.get((int)i);
            builder.append(c);
            if(c=='\n'){
                if(count==5)break;
                count++;
                builder.reverse();
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
                builder=null;
                builder=new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        channel.close();
    }
```

**RandomAccessFile to print last 5 lines:**

```
private static void printByRandomAcessFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        int lines = 0;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        long length = file.length();
        length--;
        randomAccessFile.seek(length);
        for(long seek = length; seek >= 0; --seek){
            randomAccessFile.seek(seek);
            char c = (char)randomAccessFile.read();
            builder.append(c);
            if(c == '\n'){
                builder = builder.reverse();
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
                lines++;
                builder = null;
                builder = new StringBuilder();
                if (lines == 5){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: worked for me . thanks. is that way have any inconvenient ?

Answer (score 2):

as far as I know The fastest way to read the last line of a text file is using FileUtils Apache class which is in "org.apache.commons.io". I have a two-million-line file and by using this class, it took me less than one second to find the last line. Here is the my code:

```
LineIterator lineIterator = FileUtils.lineIterator(newFile(filePath),"UTF-8");
String lastLine="";
while (lineIterator.hasNext()){
 lastLine=  lineIterator.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Same comment above by Lorenzo also applies here: This works, but is probably not the most efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(reqFile))) {

    String line = null;

    System.out.println("======================================");

    line = reader.readLine();       //Read Line ONE
    line = reader.readLine();       //Read Line TWO
    System.out.println("first line : " + line);

    //Length of one line if lines are of even length
    int len = line.length();       

    //skip to the end - 3 lines
    reader.skip((reqFile.length() - (len*3)));

    //Searched to the last line for the date I was looking for.

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

        System.out.println("FROM LINE : " + line);
        String date = line.substring(0,line.indexOf(","));

        System.out.println("DATE : " + date);      //BAM!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    }

    System.out.println(reqFile.getName() + " Read(" + reqFile.length()/(1000) + "KB)");
    System.out.println("======================================");
} catch (IOException x) {
    x.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is 2 lines only

```
     // Please specify correct Charset
     ReversedLinesFileReader rlf = new ReversedLinesFileReader(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

     // read last 2 lines
     System.out.println(rlf.toString(2));
```

Gradle:

```
implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.11.0'
```

Maven:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId><artifactId>commons-io</artifactId><version>2.11.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **C#**, you should be able to set the stream's position:

From: http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/269090-streamreader-read-last-line-text-file

```
using(FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("c:\\file.dat"))
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        sr.BaseStream.Position = fs.Length - 4;
        if(sr.ReadToEnd() == "DONE")
            // match
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java's FileInputStream (which FileReader is based on), you cannot set the position; you can only skip forward, which probably does not read the parts you skip, but is still a one-way operation and thus not suited to looking for a linebreak at an unknown offset from the end.

Comment: You can use mark() to get around that problem, depending on what the streams markLimit() is.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the Unicode problems related to reverting the string (or the StringBuilder), as discussed in [Eric Leschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file/7322581#7322581) excellent answer, one can read to a byte list, from the end of the file, revert it to a byte array and then create the String from the byte array.

Below are the changes to [Eric Leschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file/7322581#7322581) answer's code, to do it with a byte array. The code changes are below the commented lines of code:

```
static public String tail2(File file, int lines) {
    java.io.RandomAccessFile fileHandler = null;
    try {
        fileHandler = new java.io.RandomAccessFile( file, "r" );
        long fileLength = fileHandler.length() - 1;
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<Byte> sb = new ArrayList<>();
        int line = 0;

        for(long filePointer = fileLength; filePointer != -1; filePointer--){
            fileHandler.seek( filePointer );
            int readByte = fileHandler.readByte();

            if( readByte == 0xA ) {
                if (filePointer < fileLength) {
                    line = line + 1;
                }
            } else if( readByte == 0xD ) {
                if (filePointer < fileLength-1) {
                    line = line + 1;
                }
            }
            if (line >= lines) {
                break;
            }
            //sb.add( (char) readByte );
            sb.add( (byte) readByte );
        }

        //String lastLine = sb.reverse().toString();
        //Revert byte array and create String
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sb.size()];
        for (int i=0; i<sb.size(); i++) bytes[sb.size()-1-i] = sb.get(i);
        String lastLine = new String(bytes);
        return lastLine;
    } catch( java.io.FileNotFoundException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        if (fileHandler != null )
            try {
                fileHandler.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
    }
}
```