# Read and a write a file in a reverse order - Java

Tags: java, io

I have a very big file (might be even 1G) that I want to create a new file from in a reversed order (in Java).
For example:

```
Original file:

This is the first line
This is the 2nd line
This is the 3rd line

The reversed file:

This is the 3rd line
This is the 2nd line
This is the first line
```

Since the file is very big, loading the entire file to memory at once and reversing the order there might be problematic (there is a limit to the memory I can use).
How can I achieve this in Java?

Thanks

Comment: This reminds me of a (possibly interview) question (can't find it, think it was on http://programmers.stackexchange.com somewhere) where you had to sort lines in a 100Gb text file on a 120Gb disk using only 1Gb RAM.

Answer (score 6):

Nothing very direct, I'm afraid. But you can easily create some (say) ReverseBufferedRead class wrapping a [RandomAccessFile](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html).

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011345/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-reverse-order).

Answer (score 5):

Read the file by chunks of few hundreds lines, reverse the order of lines in the chunks and write them to temporary files. Then join the temporary files in the reverse order and clean up.

In other words, use disk instead of memory.

Answer (score 2):

I would propose making a RandomAccessFile for the output and using setLength() to make it appropriately sized.

Then start scanning the original file and write it out in chunks starting at the end of the RandomAccessFile in reverse.

Java-ish Pseudo:

```
out.seek(size_of_out_file); //seek to end
RandomAccessFile out = new RandomAccessFile("out_fname", "rw");
out.setLength(size_of_file_to_be_reversed)
File in = new File ("in_fname");
while (hasMoreData(in)){
  String chunk = in.readsize();
  out.seekBackwardsBy(chunk.length());
  out.write(chunk.reverse);
  out.seekBackwardsBy(chunk.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading a file line-by-line in reverse order is fundamentally tricky.

It's not *too* bad if you've got a fixed width encoding. It's feasible if you've got a variable width encoding which you can detect the first byte of etc (e.g. UTF-8). It's virtually impossible to do efficiently if the encoding is variable width with no sensible way of determining boundaries (or if it uses "shifting" for example).

I have an implementation in C# [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c/452945#452945), but it would take a fair amount of effort to port that to Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the RandomAccessFile like leonbloy suggested you can use a [FileChannel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)

to skip to the end of the file, you can then read the line and write it to another file.

There is a simple example here in the Java tutorials: [example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you know how to read a file. One way i would advise you do it is with an ArrayList of generic type string. So you read each line of the file and store it in that list. After reading you print the list out or do whatever you want to.

Just wrote something that might be of help here : http://pastebin.com/iWTVrAvm

Comment: Thanks, but the problem here is that I cannot load the entire file to memory so I cannot use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Read using `RandomAccessFile` - position the file using randomAccesFile.length()and write using `BufferedWriter`

Comment: In case of RandomAccessFile, what do you mean by "wrap around buffered classes for memory concerns"? RandomAccessFile cannot wrap BufferedReader (and of course I cannot read from the BufferedReader...), so I'm not sure what you mean here.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is use a ReversedLinesFileReader provided in  Apache Commons IO package. Look at the API here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html