# Java - read file line by line - with pagination

Tags: java, file, frameworks

I am trying to implement a simple log reader and for that I looking for a java framework (e.g. apache commons io) which does the following -

- reads a text file line by line
- provides a paging functionality - i.e. I should be able to mention the number of lines I need to read from file + get the lines from the next page start - say 50th line to 100 th line

Is there any standard framework which does this ? (dont want to reinvent the wheel here)

Comment: The "standard framework" is ... basic file IO. Open file, read lines, keep count.

Answer (score 0):

Enough to help you get started!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("myFile.txt");

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String line = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now how do I read from the bottom of the file - upwards ? (aka descending order of timestamp..)

Comment: please see this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011345/read-a-file-line-by-line-in-reverse-order