# How to read a file from end to the beginning?

Tags: java, io

How to read file from end to the beginning my code,

```
  try                
   {
      String strpath="/var/date.log";
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(strpath);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
      String ch;
      String[] Arr;
      do 
      {
        ch = br.readLine();
        if (ch != null)
        out.print(ch+"<br/>");   
      } 
      while (ch != null);
      fr.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
    out.print(e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: there isn't any error in it i wanna read file from end to the start this my code for just derading and printing file

Comment: how about just reading the file and reversing it when you're done?

Comment: That shouldn't be a big problem. But if you don't know how to do it, just stick to the `RandomAccessFile`-class as proposed by Sergey Grinev and Nrj . Sounds like the right approach

Comment: See also: [Java: Quickly read the last line of a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231), [Java : Read last n lines of a HUGE file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121678)

Comment: This question seems to have been duplicated. Its duplicate received far more answers, and some very useful ones at that: [How to read file from end to start (in reverse order) in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664705/how-to-read-file-from-end-to-start-in-reverse-order-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You can use RandomAccessFile class. Either just read in loop from file length to 0, or use some convenience 3rd party wraps like http://mattfleming.com/node/11

Answer (score 2):

If you need print lines in reverse order:

1. Read all lines to list
2. Reverse them
3. Write them back

Code:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
String curLine;
while ( (curLine= br.readLine()) != null) {
  lines.add(curLine);
}
Collections.reverse(lines);
for (String line : lines) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use temporary data(for reversing the file) you should use `RandomAccessFile` class.

In other case you can read and store the whole file in memory, then reversing it contents.

```
List<String> data = new LinkedList<String>();
```

If you need lines in reverse order, insted of:

```
out.print(ch+"<br/>");
```

do

```
data.add(ch);
```

And after reading the whole file you can use

```
Collections.reverse(data);
```

If you need every symbol to be in reverse order, you can use type `Character` instead of `String` and read not the whole line but only one symbol.
After that simply reverse your data.

P.S. To print (to system output stream for example) you should iterate over each item in collection.

```
for (String line : data) {
   out.println(line);
}
```

If you use just `out.print(data)` this will call `data.toString()` method and print out its result. Standart implementation of `toString()` will not work as you expected. It will return something like object type and number.

Comment: if we want to print data having reversed data then do we have to use out.print(data); ???