# Get the last line from a String containing many lines

Tags: java, string

I'm reading a text file line by line and converting it into a string.

I'm trying to figure out how to check if the last line of the file is a specific word `("FILTER")`.

I've tried to use the `endsWith(String)` method of String class but it's not detecting the word when it appears.

Comment: You should show the code you're using... It seems to me you may have missed something in the code that is causing your issues.

Comment: I agree with Romain. Can you also show an example file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Quickly read the last line of a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/java-quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

Comment: dogbane this is not a duplicate ,he needs to check whether a word is present in last line of a file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   public static boolean compareInFile(String inputWord) {     

         String word = "";     

        File file = new File("Deepak.txt");     
        try {     
            Scanner input = new Scanner(file);     
            while (input.hasNext()) {     
                word = input.next();     
                if (inputWord.equals(word)) {     
                    return true;     
                }     
            }     

        } catch (Exception error) {     
       }     
        return false;     
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

Rather naive solution, but this should work:

```
String[] lines = fileContents.split("\n");
String lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1];
if("FILTER".equals(lastLine)){
// Do Stuff
}
```

Not sure why .endsWith() wouldn't work. Is there an extra newline at the end? (In which case the above wouldn't work). Do the cases always match?

Answer (score 1):

`.trim()` your string before checking with `endsWith(..)` (if the file really ends with the desired string. If not, you can simply use `.contains(..)`)

Answer (score 0):

With

```
myString.endsWith("FILTER")
```

the very last characters of the last line are checked. Maybe the method

```
myString.contains("FILTER")
```

is the right method for you? If you only want to check the last ... e.g.20 chars try to substring the string and then check for the equals method.