# Deleting the last line of a file with Java

Tags: java, file-io, text-processing

I have a `.txt` file, which I want to process in Java. I want to delete its last line.

I need ideas on how to achieve this without having to copy the entire content into another file and ignoring the last line.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Important question. Such thing gives ability to work with big files with low RAM usage and low IO operations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could find the beginning of the last line by scanning the file and then truncate it using [`FileChannel.truncate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate%28long%29) or [`RandomAccessFile.setLength`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#setLength%28long%29).

Comment: This does only work on byte basis, wouldn't you have to do the encoding related size calculations by yourself?

Comment: Obviously, this depends on the encoding. Byte-wise searching for a new-line character (\0x0a) in ASCII or Latin-1 encoding (or other encodings with 1 byte per character) is safe. I believe that doing this for UTF-8 is safe, too, because all multi-byte sequences have the high bit set. It would fail for, e.g., UTF-16.

Comment: You are right, for typical encodings including UTF-8 this should not be a problem (as long as you can define "line ending", that is ;-)).

Comment: No solution for getting the position of the last new line sign

Answer (score 1):

By using `RandomAccessFile` you can:

- find the position of the last new line character. To read the position: **getFilePointer()**. To truncate the file: **setLength(long)**.
- optimization: to read only end of the file use method **seek(long)** to jump ahead. Challenge is to define the jump.

Otherwise read whole file and store only the last position of the "\n". // Unix new line convention

```
import java.io.*;

public class TruncateFileExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename = "path/to/your/file.txt";

        try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw")) {
            long fileLength = raf.length();
            if (fileLength == 0) {
                // File is empty, nothing to delete
                return;
            }

            // Start searching for the last newline character from the end of the file
            long position = fileLength - 1;
            raf.seek(position);

            int lastByte;
            while ((lastByte = raf.read()) != -1) {
                if (lastByte == '\n') {
                    // Found the last newline character
                    break;
                }
                position--;
                raf.seek(position);
            }

            // Truncate the file at the position of the last newline character
            raf.setLength(position);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah! That code's really long! Any way to do this without so much code?

Comment: I made it shorter but without skipping most part of the file.