# Delete last line in text file

Tags: java

I am tying to erase the last line in a text file using Java; however, the code below deletes everything.

```
public void eraseLast()
{
    while(reader.hasNextLine()) {
        reader.nextLine();

        if (!reader.hasNextLine()) {
            try {
                fWriter = new FileWriter("config/lastWindow.txt");

                writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
                writer.write("");
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting the last line of a file with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149648/deleting-the-last-line-of-a-file-with-java)

Comment: The answers presented are all inneficient.  they will loop through a 2 gig file instead of just truncating the file.  What you want to do is find the last line ending and truncate: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#truncate(long)

Comment: @DMoses , thank you very much for saying that,i am very interested in performance so I will do that

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you wanted to delete the last line from the file without creating a new file, you could do something like this:

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
long length = f.length() - 1;
do {                     
  length -= 1;
  f.seek(length);
  byte b = f.readByte();
} while(b != 10);
f.setLength(length+1);
f.close();
```

Start off at the second last byte, looking for a linefeed character, and keep seeking backwards until you find one. Then truncate the file after that linefeed.

You start at the second last byte rather than the last in case the last character is a linefeed (i.e. the end of the last line).

Comment: you shoud add `&& length>0` to the while condition

Comment: Why b != 10? Not sure how this 10 bytes comes into play. Is that EOF?

Comment: Because it´s the ASCII code. ```10  LF  (NL line feed, new line)``` https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html

Comment: @James Holderness, how can I change the `10 LF` part to delete the last 2 lines instead of only one?

Comment: scope check my guy, b isn't defined in the while's condition

Answer (score 9):

You are creating a new file that's replacing the old one, you want something like this

```
public void eraseLast() {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = reader.readLine();
        if (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            s.append(line);
        }
    }
    try {
        fWriter = new FileWriter("config/lastWindow.txt");
        writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);

        writer.write(s.toString());

        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the only reason why I didn t choose your answer was because I used James Holdernesss' answer

Comment: The only important thing is that you find a solution to your problem :)

Answer (score 6):

The answer above needs to be slightly modified to deal with the case where there is only 1 line left in the file (otherwise you get an IOException for negative seek offset):

```
RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
long length = f.length() - 1;
do {                     
  length -= 1;
  f.seek(length);
  byte b = f.readbyte();
} while(b != 10 && length > 0);
if (length == 0) { 
f.setLength(length);
} else {
f.setLength(length + 1);
}
```

Comment: And you would need to check whether the filesize is greater than 0 or not ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You're opening the file in overwrite mode (hence a single `write` operation will wipe the entire contents of the file), to open it in append mode it should be:

```
fWriter = new FileWriter("config/lastWindow.txt", true);
```

And besides, it's not going to delete the *last* line: although the reader has reached the current last line of the file, the writer is *after* the last line - because we specified above that the append mode should be used.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149648/deleting-the-last-line-of-a-file-with-java) to get an idea of what you'll have to do.

Answer (score 2):

I benefited from others but the code was not working. Here is my working code on android studio.

```
File file = new File(getFilesDir(), "mytextfile.txt");
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
byte b;
long length = randomAccessFile.length() ;
if (length != 0) {
    do {
        length -= 1;
        randomAccessFile.seek(length);
        b = randomAccessFile.readByte();
    } while (b != 10 && length > 0);
    randomAccessFile.setLength(length);
    randomAccessFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
private fun removeLastSegment() {
    val reader = BufferedReader(FileReader(segmentsFile))
    val segments = ArrayList<Segment>()
    var line: String?
    while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
        segments.add(Gson().fromJson(line, Segment::class.java))
    }
    reader.close()

    segments.remove(segments.last())
    var writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(segmentsFile))
    writer.write("")
    writer = BufferedWriter(FileWriter(segmentsFile, true))
    for (segment in segments) {
        writer.appendLine(Gson().toJson(segment))
    }
    writer.flush()
    writer.close()
    lastAction--
    lastSegment--
}
```