# How can I remove last 2 lines in text file in Java?

Tags: java, io

I want remove last 2 lines in my text file using java. I tried 4 or 5 different ways about this, but I can't find working code. I will edit file like this:

```
[
    {
        "example"
    }
]
```

I want delete "]" , "}" and add "example2". How can I do that ?
(I'm using SE 1.8 , maybe version have an effect on this)

Can you recommend anything ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which 4 or 5 ways did you try?

Comment: I looked at sites like this on stack overflow but the codes on these sites did not work or I could not write correct

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732417/delete-last-line-in-text-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try reading the file, then writing it all over again but without the last 2 lines:

```
public void removeLastLines() {
    int lines = 2; //This is the number that determines how many we remove
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))){
        List<String> lineStorage = new ArrayList<>();
        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine()) !=null) {
            lineStorage.add(line);
        }
        try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))){
            int lines1 = lineStorage.size()-lines;
            for(int i = 0; i < lines1; i++) {
                bw.write(lineStorage.get(i));
                bw.newLine();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```