# Reading a Remote File Partially Without Downloading Completely

Tags: java, file-io, remote-access

Is it possible to write a program that reads last N lines of a big file that is located on a remote machine (accessible via network) without downloading all the file to local machine? The implementation should be only on local computer, it is not possible to make changes on the remote.

If it is possible how can we do that in Java?

Comment: You would something at the remote location that would do that for you.

Comment: What means 'accessible via network'? NFS, Windows share, what kind of protocol used?

Comment: no I want a solution on local machine. nothing should be done on remote one.

Comment: Since the file is at the remote location, you need something that runs in that machine and reads the required N lines of the file.

Comment: @BheshGurung of course you can do that and it is a trivial solution. I edited the question.

Comment: @Serge does it matter if it's accessible via NFS or windows share?

Comment: May be you are looking for something that can do what a **tail** command does.

Comment: @paritybit no, just gave some hints to make my question more clear. It does matter if a file is accessed over a plain socket connection to some proprietary service:)

Comment: @BheshGurung but this requires an extra SSH permission and I only have access to the file.

Comment: @paritybit  Again, what you mean 'I have access'

Comment: @Serge actually it is shared using a samba server on a linux machine.

Comment: fine. then why you can't use lseek (or equivalent) to get your file pointer in a right position?

Comment: you move the pointer 1k before the end of file and read 1k. if you have there 10 lines - you are done. if not - then you read 1k before the last 1k block. e.t.c.

Comment: Also the file is server by an NFS, and I can mount it on the local machine. Would this make thing different? Anyway the file should be downloaded i guess.

Comment: This is what I ask. When using lseek on a remote file, how does system behave in background? Does it download the file completely, or can it access it partially?

Comment: it adjusts the file pointer. No need to transfer the data if the protocol is a normal file system networking protocol, like SMB or NFS

Answer (score 0):

You should use un-buffered io functions to open and access the file (`open`/`read`/`lseek` or `CreateFile`/`ReadFile`/`SetFilePointer`). Then you `open` the file, and seek to location close to the end of file: `lseek(fd,SEEK_END,-1024)`. Then you read 1024 bytes from the file and scan the data read for a line termination sequence. If the number of rows less than N+1 then you seek again but with offset -2048 and read extra 1024 bytes. You iterate the process until you see N+1 line termination sequences in the data you buffered.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

See the following: [Quickly read the last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/java-quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

They also provide an example on how to read the last N lines of a file. 
By Using the seek command you skip the bytes which you do not want to read.