# Reading the last line of CSV file using openCSV in Java

Tags: java, opencsv

How to read only the last line of a csv file using openCSV.? Is there any way instead of reading the entire file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't *need* to use openCSV, you could use an implementation around [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html). Here is a nice, working [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322581/1713801) (two actually, but one is more generic). Take into account the warnings in the end of that answer.

Also, Apache Commons has [ReversedLinesFileReader](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/input/ReversedLinesFileReader.html), with `readLine` method that "returns the lines of the file from bottom to top", though it should be tested if the entire file is not being read.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the number of lines in the cvs file then you can do the following to skip all lines before the last line:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), ',', '\'', num_of_lines-1);
```

Comment: Thanks. But the number of lines is not known.