# Follow a file like tail in Unix

Tags: java, file-io, io, while-loop

I'm trying a tail implementation of the follow option in java. It is supposed to print the last ten lines from a dynamically changing file. How exactly is one supposed to keep the program running. What should be the while loop condition?

```
while (true) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                long len = file.length();
                long pointer = r.getFilePointer();
                if (len < pointer) {
                    //Do something
                }
                else if (len > pointer) {
                   //Do something
                }
             }
```

Comment: That should work? I mean, it will just run forever now...

Comment: It keeps printing every 1000 mili seconds. I want it to print to console only if a change has been made in the file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java IO implementation of unix/linux "tail -f"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/557844/java-io-implementation-of-unix-linux-tail-f)

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.*;

public class Tail {
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

File f = new File( args[0] );
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( f );
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( fis );
FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
String line = null;
    long pos = fc.size();
    fc.position( pos );  // Positioning by using a FileChannel to reach EOF

    for(;;){
       Thread.sleep( 100 );
       long newpos = fc.size();  // Monitor new position
       while( pos < newpos ){    // new data?
           int c = bis.read();   // read and print
           System.out.print( (char)c );
           pos++;
       }
       pos = newpos;
    }
}
}
```

This inner loop is even better as there's only one bulk read and one write.

```
    if( newpos > pos ){
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( (int)(newpos - pos) );
        fc.read( buffer );
        System.out.print( new String( buffer.array()) );
        pos = newpos;
    }
```

Comment: Some comments would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the last modification time from the metadata of your file. use `f.lastModified()`
2. If the time has changed dump the data from the line of last file size till end. Use random access file to reach till the desired point in the file fast.

   ```
   RandomAccessFile raF = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
   raF.seek(f.length());
   ```
3. Save a pointer to the last line now.

Read more here -

https://freethreads.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/how-tail-f-work/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_lastmodified.htm

**Code:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    File f = new File("/home/mangat/hi");   
    RandomAccessFile raF = new RandomAccessFile(f, "r");
    long time = 0;
    String line = "";

    //First reach then end, No need to print already present content

    long fSize= f.length();
    while( line != null )  
    {               line = raF.readLine();  
    }  
    raF.seek(fSize);
    time = f.lastModified();

    //Now print the additions in the file from now on

    while (true) {
      if (time != f.lastModified()) {
       // System.out.println("changed");
        time = f.lastModified();
        System.out.println(f.length());
        raF.seek(f.length());
        line = raF.readLine();  
        while( line != null )  
        {   
           System.out.println(line);
           line = raF.readLine();  
        }  
      }

      Thread.sleep(100);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing it (I'm sure there are better ways) is store the last line of file in a variable outside the loop, update it every loop and only print out if something has changed, something like:

```
String oldLastLine;
String newLastLine;

while (true) {
    // sleep

    newLastLine = // read lastLine
    if (oldLastLine.equals(newLastLine)) {
        continue;
    }

    // check pointers

    oldLastLine = newLastLine;
}
```

To read the last line and in general more info about tail look at:
[Quickly read the last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

About the code:
It will basically skip the current iteration and won't do anything if the line hasn't changed.
I haven't tested it so it may not work, but I hope you get the idea.

**Edit:**

As people have commented, this is not a fool-proof method, however, if you want to keep it simple you could read the last few lines. Furthermore, if you'd look at the link I gave previously, you'd find a working implementation of tail in Java.

Comment: What is line are added to fast? Reading last line only could make you miss some lines.

What if same line was written twice? You will miss that too!

Comment: What happens if lines are repeated? -1

Comment: Yeah fair enough, but if you wanted keep it simple you can just read the last few lines. Also, I gave a link to an answer that shows how to implement tail in Java.