# Check if a new line exists at end of file

Tags: java, file

I created a simple method to append text to a file:

```
void writeFile(String fileName, String... values) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        for (String value: values) {
            bw.write(value);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I am at a loss on how to check if a new line exists at the end of the file before writing to ensure that it is stored properly.

Also, it would have to be scalable for when working with larger files.

Comment: Do you want to check before or after writing to the file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quickly read the last line of a text file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

Comment: Also, don't forget to close your writer (`bw.close()`), which will flush the stream making sure everything is put to the file before the program ends.

Comment: @KSFT Before, because after it would have a new line from bw.newLine()

Comment: @jas When using the try with resources syntax wouldn't be closed automatically?

Comment: @Jsilvermist Yes it will. I think jas overlooked the try-with-resources statement

Comment: Indeed I did miss that, sorry!! No need for the explicit close.

Comment: Since you write a newline at the end of the file, why do you worry at all about it?

Comment: @fge Because the file it's writing to might not always have a new line, since it could be user editable.

Comment: So you mean to test that prior to writing the new contents?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to SMA linking to [Quickly read the last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file), I was able to create a method to check if a new line exists, and then create a new line if it doesn't.

```
static void writeFile(String fileName, String... values) {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    boolean fileExists = file.exists();
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        if (fileExists && !newLineExists(file)) {
            bw.newLine();
        }
        for (String value : values) {
            bw.write(value);
            bw.newLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

static boolean newLineExists(File file) throws IOException {
  try (RandomAccessFile fileHandler = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r")) {
    long fileLength = fileHandler.length() - 1;
    if (fileLength < 0) {
      return true;
    }
    fileHandler.seek(fileLength);
    byte readByte = fileHandler.readByte();

    return readByte == 0xA || readByte == 0xD;
  }
}
```