# How do I read the last line of a text file in java?

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, filereader

I'm trying to write a method for a program that only reads the last line of the text file, but I can't find out what the issue is and I have been searching for a while. Any help would be amazing.

```
public String getLastLine(String path) throws IOException {
    String st;
    String ot = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            ot = st;
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ot;
    
}
```

Everything I have been able to find tells me to create a string and set it to null or to set it to "", but this isn't working at all for me. I keep getting this error code

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[BZHbzAauZi]> but was:<[]>
```

I tried to return the last line of a text file but it only returns as a empty space.

Comment: Could be stating the obvious, but is the last line in the file empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickly read the last line of a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686231/quickly-read-the-last-line-of-a-text-file)

Comment: If the file ends with a newline sequence, the last line is, in fact, the empty string.

Comment: @VGR - that's not so.  A file that contains a total 4 chars "foo\n" certainly ends with a newline, but the last line is not empty.  The file has exactly one line, which is non-empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
  if(st.isBlank()) {
    continue;
   }
   ot = st;
 }
```

Will preserve the last-read, non-blank line.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked! Programming makes me feel stupid. I was working on it before you answered and I was thinking of a if statement like that but instead of thinking to use what you wrote I was doing if (st.equals(""). Thanks again that was driving me crazy.

Comment: **On a side:** To do this below Java 11: `if(st.trim().isEmpty()) { continue; }`