# Tail -n 1000 in Java (Apache commons, etc)

Tags: java, tail

I'm wondering if util code already exists to implement some/all of *NIX tail. I'd like to copy the last n lines of some file/reader to another file/reader, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a good bet: [Tailer Library](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=226). [This implementation](http://snipplr.com/view/4859/simple-tail-like-assertion/) is based on it, but isn't the same. Neither implement a lookback to get the last 100 lines though. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at this [tail implementation](http://crawler.archive.org/xref-test/org/archive/crawler/util/LogReader.html#762) in one of [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org)'s utility classes. I didn't write it but I wrote the code that uses it, works correctly as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

This is a UI app - you can look at the source though to see what it does (basically some threading & IO). [Follow](http://follow.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

The "last n lines" is quite tricky to do with potentially variable width encodings etc.

I wrote a reverse line iterator in C# in response to [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c). The code is all there, although it uses iterator blocks which aren't available in C# - you'd probably be better off passing the desired size into the method and getting it to build a list. (You can then convert the `yield return` statements in my code into `list.add()` calls.) You'll need to use a Java `Charset` instead of `Encoding` of course, and their APIs are slightly different too. Finally, you'll need to reverse the list when you're done.

This is all assuming you *don't* want to just read the whole file. If you don't mind doing that, you could use a circular buffer to keep "the last n lines at the moment", reading through until the end and returning the buffer afterwards. That would be much *much* simpler to implement, but will be much less efficient for very long files. It's easy to make that cope with *any* reader though, instead of just a few selected charsets over a stream (which my reverse iterator does).