# NLog write file log on top of file

Tags: c#, nlog

How to write log as newest on the first in file? Is there some configuration?

Comment: It is an expensive operation - to write on the top of the file. I would amaze if it exists in any logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will not find any logger which can do that since the whole file have to be rewritten each time a new log entry is added.

Find a log viewer which can view the log in reverse order instead. Is a lot more resource efficient.

**Update**

Here is a stream which reads a file backwards:
[How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c)

Comment: Ok, is it possible to read file backwards? How to do it in c#?