# How to read a text file from last line to first line in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)

I wanted to know how to read a text file from last line to first line in c#.

I am using this code for reading a text file

```
            using (var sr = File.OpenText("C:\\test.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                bool flag = true;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                }
            }
```

I dont know how to read Backwards.

There would be a great appreciation if someone could help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Do check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp, it specifically mentions not reading the entire file into memory which the answers posted here so far seem to be doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to reverse the collection of read lines

```
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    using (var sr = File.OpenText("C:\\test.txt"))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines.Add(line); 
        }
    }

    lines.Reverse();
```

Comment: Joe Whites solution is much better, because it uses only one file access.

Comment: I suggest to try with a file sized a couple of Gigabytes...

Answer (score 10):

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Reverse()
```

Comment: Great, mine is nonsense and will be deleted.

Comment: @SharrokG Fine, so be nice, accept his answer and give him the points. ;-)

Comment: how can i use this in my code to read reverse can u pls say me

Comment: @SharrokG, I take it you've never used C# before? Try this: `var reversedLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.txt").Reverse(); foreach (var line in reversedLines) DoSomething(line);` where you write the `DoSomething` part.

Comment: Too bad answer for performance wise..