# Reading last symbol from text file using C#

Tags: c#, file-io

What is the most efficient way to read the last symbol or line of a large text file using C#?

Comment: _How_ large is the file?

Comment: +1 for the question. It's been intriguing to see how many ways there are to actually skin the cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the file is not *too large*, just read the lines and pick the last:

```
string lastLine = File.ReadLines("pathToFile").LastOrDefault(); // if the file is empty
```

So you get the last character in this way:

```
Char lastChar = '\0';
if(lastLine  != null) lastChar = lastLine.LastOrDefault();
```

[`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) does not need to read all lines before it can start processsing, so it's cheap in terms of memory consumption.

Here is the more complicated way from J. Skeet: [How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: it will select last line only not last symbol!!

Comment: @NeelBhatt: Already edited :)

Comment: oh ok sorry :) but are you sure lastline.Last() will give last character? coz i have some doubt on that!!

Comment: @NeelBhatt Why not give a try? that should work. btw if your file doesn't contains any lines this is going to throw `InvalidOperationException` take care of that

Comment: ohh yeah i havnt tried it ever yet so thts the reason its creating doubt for me but anyways thanx it should work then :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: Good point, you can use `LastOrDefault` but then you need to handle the case that `lastLine` is `null`. Edited my answer to take that into account.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning in your answer @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your text file is ASCII, this method will allow you to jump straight to the last character and avoid reading the rest of the file (like all the other answers given so far do).

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    stream.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.End);
    byte b = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
    char c = (char)b;
}
```

If your program needs to handle multi-byte encodings, you might need to perform some complex logic, as shown is [Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/1149773). However, given that your case is restricted just to reading the last character, you can implement a simplified version specific to your expected encoding. The code below works for UTF-8 (which is the most popular encoding today). The `Seek` may land your reader in the middle of a preceding character, but the decoder will recover from this by the time it reads the last character.

```
FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
int maxBytesPerChar = Encoding.UTF8.GetMaxByteCount(1);
int readLength = Math.Min(maxBytesPerChar, (int)fileInfo.Length);

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    reader.DiscardBufferedData();
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(-readLength, SeekOrigin.End);

    string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
    char c = s.Last();
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting. +1. How does this work 'under the hood'? Surely it would have to read the entirety of the file in some sort of fashion first to know 'where' the last byte is?

Comment: @DeeMac There is not really any "under the hood". It uses ".Seek()" which maps to the Windows API function [`SetFilePointer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @DeeMac: No. The operating system records the file length, so it wouldn't need to be traversed each time it is read.

Comment: Understood. Will keep this in mind. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
string[] split = s.Split(s[s.Length - 1]);
```

and for last line :-

```
var lastLine = File.ReadLines("test.txt").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line[line.length-1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use the ReadToEnd-Method of the File-Class, so you don't need to close the Steam/TextReader:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(@"YOUR PATH HERE");
char lastchar = s[s.Length - 1];
```

Answer (score -1):

Fastes method:

```
var lines = new ReverseLineReader(filename);
var last = lines.Take(1);
```

You can read more [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)