# Reading appended line from bottom of logfile

Tags: c#, .net

Scenario is the following:

- A (weather) service dumps sensor data into a log file/text file.
- The new readings are appended to the bottom of a given (existing) file
- New data is added at regular intervals (interval may or may not be known)

I need to parse the new information/line and send it off to another service.

I don't want to read the whole file every time, unless I have to.

EDIT: Sorry for the bad wording. "unless I have to" should be understood as if there is no other way around. I have seen the post/answer referenced and it seems a little extensive.

Framework is 4.5.x.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your requirements. Any attempt to solve them?

Answer (score 2):

To get the the last line of a text file you can use this

```
File.ReadLines(myFileName).Last();
```

This is the simplest method, but is inefficient. You can write your own parser as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti "unless I have to" being the operative phrase

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti unless he wants to code this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp , he has to

Comment: Fair enough but I'd elaborate little bit more...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti amended the answer