# Find the last occurrence of substring in string in a large text file

Tags: regex, vb.net, lastindexof

I'm trying to read through a huge text file, approx 10 gigabytes.
I want to find the last occurrence of a string.

e.g below is a sample of 5 lines the 2nd and 5th are the same string.
I want to take the last one as it is the latest and output that to a text file using streamreader.

Am I better off using Regex or am I better off using a `lastindexof` to determine if it is the last string?

I have a lot of these searches to do so I would create some kind of array and have it search from bottom up to improve performance.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
GET/a/users/115656WindowsNT6.1;Trident
GET/a/users/126692MSIE7.0;WindowsNT6.1
GET/a/users/77562WindowsNT6.1;WOW64;Tr
GET/a/users/35650WindowsNT6.1;WOW64;Tr
GET/a/users/126692MSIE7.0;WindowsNT6.2
```

Comment: You say you have 10 gigs of these data. I'd use an sqlite-based solution, reading in the data into a DB, and then getting just distinct values. I would not be using any regex here, *unless* you also want to get specific patterns from those strings. Since the lines are identical, it makes no sense getting just the last occurrence (last = first).

Comment: See http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/109316-reading-large-text-file-line-line-backwards for a possible solution.

Comment: Really you're looking at reading the file backwards and checking lines as you go. Reading backwards is difficult though. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes.. you can use datastore based solution.. it will be faster and efficient than using regex..

Comment: Try a search for "file random access." If your records are of fixed record length it should be pretty easy to get the last N records and copy those to a string.

Comment: how do you identify the substring you want to find? in your example lines 2 and 5 differ in the last character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `File.ReadLines` is one of the best ways to read the large files according to [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, **when you are working with very large files**,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

So depending on this I wrote the following code and I hope it help :

```
Dim myList As List(Of String) = IO.File.ReadLines("MyLargFile.txt").OfType(Of String)().Where(Function(s) s.Contains("126692MSIE7")).ToList
```

This piece of code will return you a list of match string lines.

**Output :**

```
myList(0) = "GET/a/users/126692MSIE7.0;WindowsNT6.1" 
myList(1) = "GET/a/users/126692MSIE7.0;WindowsNT6.2"
```

And of course if need the last line you may use the `Last` method:

```
Dim last As String = myList.Last
```