# Get the line number of last occurrence of a particular string with [Linq.Enumerable] in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, linq

Is there a way to get the line index of the last occurrence in file, not the line itself?

```
$delegate = [Func[string,bool]] {$args[0] -match $myString}
$lastCheckIn  = [Linq.Enumerable]::Last([System.IO.File]::ReadLines($myFile), $delegate)
```

I thought of using `[Linq.Enumerable]::Count` but couldn't find a method to return a sequence from the start to `$lastCheckIn`.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to find/count... When you say "the index of the last occurrence", do you mean the _line_ index, the _character_ position or the _byte_ offset? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I’m looking for the line index, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limiting the approach to Linq, you can try the following.

```
$lines = 'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd'
$searchPattern = 'c+'

$selectDelegate = [Func[object, int32, object]] { @{line=$args[0]; index=$args[1] } }
$whereDelegate = [Func[object,bool]] { $args[0].line -match $searchPattern }

$objects = [Linq.Enumerable]::Select($lines, $selectDelegate)
$lastObject = [Linq.Enumerable]::Last($objects, $whereDelegate)
$lastObject.index
# result = 6 (zero-based index)

# Without Linq
$lines | Select-String $searchPattern | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LineNumber
# result = 7 (one-based index)
```

This first builds up a collection of line/index pairs, filters for the last match, and then extract the index. I've also included a non-linq powershell equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should be faster and easier to implement, maintain and understand:

```
$pattern = 'yourpatternhere'
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines('path/to/file.ext')
$tail = $content.Count

while($tail--)
{
    if($content[$tail] -match $pattern)
    {
        "$pattern was found on line: $tail"
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it is very clear and easy to understand, but I have many matches and need only the last one

Comment: @Marisol thats what this is doing, returning only the last one...

Comment: Right, I'm so sorry, absolutely correct

Answer (score 1):

[T N's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70885992/45375) shows an effective LINQ solution as well as a PowerShell-idiomatic alternative.

There are two alternatives for *improved performance*:

- If it is acceptable to load the entire file into memory first, use [`[Array]::FindLastIndex()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Array.FindLastIndex) (`Get-Content -ReadCount 0` is in essence the PowerShell equivalent of `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines()`):

```sh
[Array]::FindLastIndex(
  (Get-Content -ReadCount 0 $myFile), # -ReadCount 0 returns all lines as single array
  [Predicate[string]] { $args[0] -match $myString }
)
```

- An optimized LINQ solution, with lazy enumeration:

```sh
$i = $index = -1
$null = [Linq.Enumerable]::LastOrDefault(
  [IO.File]::ReadLines($myFile),
  [Func[string, bool]] { 
     ++$script:i; 
     if ($args[0] -match $myString) { $script:index = $script:i; return $true } 
  }
)
$index # output the index of the last match, if not found, -1
```

*Caveat*: This approach to finding the index only works as intended with *lazy* enumerables as input, as only they necessitate *forward* enumeration until the very last element.

By contrast, *list-like* enumerables (those that implement the [`System.Collections.IList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.IList) interface or its generic counterpart), are enumerated *backwards*, from the *end* of the list, for optimized performance.

Similarly, if you expect the last matching line to be close(r) to the *end* of the large file, you'll need to lazily read the file *backwards* for best performance, for which there is no standard .NET API. Doing so in a way that handles variable-width character encodings such as UTF-8 is nontrivial, however - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/45375).

Comment: Thank you, it is a 1GB file so I was looking for the least memory and CPU consuming option

Comment: I see, @Marisol; then the optimized LINQ solution could work for you. Ultimately, however, if you expect the last matching line to be close(r) to the _end_ of the large file, you'll need to read the file _backwards_ for best performance. Unfortunately, doing so in a way that handles variable-width character encodings such as UTF-8 is nontrivial - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/45375).