# Read from a file starting at the end, similar to tail

Tags: c#, file-io

In native C#, how can I read from the end of a file?

This is pertinent because I need to read a log file, and it doesn't make sense to read 10k, to read the last 3 lines.

Comment: 10KB is not that much :)

Comment: Its worth noting that if you need a utility baretail for Windows works really good.

Comment: @cfeduke Need to regex the last line in an app.  Thanks though.

Comment: See also: [Get last 10 lines of very large text file > 10GB c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398378), [How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

To read the last 1024 bytes:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("foo.txt"))
{
    if (reader.BaseStream.Length > 1024)
    {
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);
    }
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work with character sets (such as UTF-8) that can use multiple bytes to encode a character? It seems you could end up starting from the middle of a multi-byte sequence.

Comment: You would have to test what I'm about to say but, if you know the character size (2 bytes for UTF8) of your string and you use a seek offset that is divisible by that number, that _**should**_ prevent you from reading anything i the middle of a character. I've never seen a stream return anything but file contents (i.e. you never get an end of file marker or other characters that aren't a part of the file).

Comment: This didn't quite read the last line for me, but instead read a number of lines up

Comment: @AndrewBonsall UTF8 is not 2-bytes per character, it's variable bytes per character 1-4 for each character. UTF16 is 2-bytes fixed per character.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);

    int newLines = 0;
    while (newLines < 3)
    {
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
        newLines += fs.ReadByte() == 13 ? 1 : 0; // look for \r
        fs.Seek(-1, SeekOrigin.Current);
    }

    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length - fs.Position];
    fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
}
```

Take note that this assumes `\r\n`.

Comment: If formulated by doubts into this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369278/filestream-seek-vs-buffered-reading

Comment: +1 To show how one can scan for lines. Side note: checking for `13` byte-by-byte assumes ASCII/UTF8 encoding. If you don't know what encoding of the file is this may not work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The code below uses a random-access `FileStream` to seed a `StreamReader` at an offset near the end of the file, discarding the first read line since it is most likely only partial.

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"c:\temp\build.txt", 
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

stream.Seek(-1024, SeekOrigin.End);     // rewind enough for > 1 line

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
reader.ReadLine();      // discard partial line

while (!reader.EndOfStream)
{
    string nextLine = reader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(nextLine);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [related question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/452945/2799848) to read a **text file** in reverse. There is a lot of complexity to reading a file backward *correctly* because of stuff like encoding.

Comment: Only answer that accounts for Encoding, which is a pretty big detail