# c# Seek vs Read

Tags: c#, performance, file, seek

Why is it better to read a file slowly to make a seek?

```
//if (!read_fields[x] || !ok)
                    //{
                    //    if (l > 0) Seek(l, SeekOrigin.Current);
                    //    read[x] = null;
                    //    continue;
                    //}

                    byte[] bx = new byte[l];
                    if (l > 0) Read(bx, 0, l);

                    if (!read_fields[x] || !ok)
                    {
                        read[x] = null;
                        continue;
                    }
```

My speed test says that seek is very slow!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369278/filestream-seek-vs-buffered-reading

Answer (score 2):

[Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) - Sets the current position of this stream to the given value.
[Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) - Reads a block of bytes from the stream and writes the data in a given buffer.

So, with seek you repositioning read position - it is time consuming process. If you simple read - you sequentially read from file.