# Reading the 2 last line from a text

Tags: c#

i am new to [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) and i am working on an app that display the time difference from two date on the last two line on a text file.

I want to read the before last line from a file text, i already know how to read the last line but i need to read the before last.

This is my code :

```
var lastLine = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log").Last();
                richTextBox1.Text = lastLine.ToString();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since

```
 File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log");
```

returns an *array* you can take the last two items of the array:

```
 var data = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log");

 string last = data[data.Length - 1];
 string lastButOne = data[data.Length - 2];
```

In *general* case with *long* files (and that's why `ReadAllLines` is a bad choice) you can implement

```
public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<T> Tail<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    else if (count < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
    else if (0 == count)
      yield break;

    Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>(count + 1);

    foreach (var item in source) {
      queue.Enqueue(item);

      if (queue.Count > count)
        queue.Dequeue();
    }

    foreach (var item in queue)
      yield return item;
  }
}
```

...

```
var lastTwolines = File
  .ReadLines("C:\\test.log") // Not all lines
  .Tail(2);
```

Answer (score 5):

All the previous answers eagerly load all the file up in memory before returning the requested last lines. This can be an issue if the file is big. Luckily, it is easily avoidable.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLastLines(string path, int count)
{
    if (count < 1)
        return Enumerable.Empty<string>();

    var queue = new Queue<string>(count);

    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))
    {
        if (queue.Count == count)
            queue.Dequeue();

         queue.Enqueue(line);
    }

    return queue;
}
```

This will only keep in memory the last `n` read lines avoiding memory issues with large files.

Comment: You still have to iterate over all lines which is inefficient for large files. See the linked questions in my answer.

Comment: @Staeff well yes of course, but its orders of magnitude more efficient than actually loading the whole file up in memory which is what the other solutions based on `ReadAllLines` do.

Comment: @InBetween But still using `StreamReader` would be more efficient as I stated in my answer. It makes no sense to load whole file when you only need 2 last lines.

Comment: @m.rogalski where am I loading up the whole file? `ReadLines` produces an `IEnumerable<string>` that simply spits out the next line in the file as long as there is one. Anyhow, your solution and mine are identical, sorry I didn't read past `StreamReader` because its not necessary, `ReadLines` works just as well.

Comment: @InBetween My bad. I though it's `ReadAllLines` like in other answers.

Comment: @m.rogalski np. My answer and yours are the same, I'll delete this one because it doesn't bring much more to the table and yours was first (my bad for not reading it completely). Simply edit yours to use `ReadLines`, it reads better and its simpler.

Comment: No need to delete any. Both differs in the sense of logical approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to do this

```
var lastLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log").Reverse().Take(2).Reverse();
```

But depending on how large your file is there are probably more efficient methods to process this than reading all lines at once. See [Get last 10 lines of very large text file > 10GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398378/get-last-10-lines-of-very-large-text-file-10gb) and [How to read last “n” lines of log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619735/how-to-read-last-n-lines-of-log-file)

Comment: Reverse the while file, take two elements and reverse it again? Seems odd to me, but should work.

Comment: The second reverse is only needed if you care about the order of the lines, guessing from her problem description it's probably not necessary but just to give a complete answer I included it.

Answer (score 2):

Simply store the result of `ReadAllLines` to a variable and than take the two last ones:

```
var allText = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log");
var lastLines = allText.Skip(allText.Length - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Skip()` and `Take()` like

```
var lastLine = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\test.log");
var data = lastLine.Skip(lastLine.Length - 2);
                richTextBox1.Text = lastLine.ToString();
```

Comment: Your `Take` is superfluous since after skip you know you only have 2 items left.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `StreamReader` in a combination of `Queue<string>` since you have to read whole file either way.

```
// if you want to read more lines change this to the ammount of lines you want
const int LINES_KEPT = 2;

Queue<string> meQueue = new Queue<string>();
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\test.log")) )
{
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ( ( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
    {
        if ( meQueue.Count == LINES_KEPT  )
           meQueue.Dequeue();

        meQueue.Enqueue(line);
    }
}
```

Now you can just use these 2 lines like such :

```
string line1 = meQueue.Dequeue(); 
string line2 = meQueue.Dequeue(); // <-- this is the last line.
```

Or to add this to the `RichTextBox` :

```
richTextBox1.Text = string.Empty; // clear the text
while ( meQueue.Count != 0 )
{
    richTextBox1.Text += meQueue.Dequeue(); // add all lines in the same order as they were in file
}
```

Using `File.ReadAllLines` will read the whole text and then using `Linq` will iterate through already red lines. This method does everything in one run.

Answer (score 1):

```
string line;
string[] lines = new string[]{"",""};
int index = 0;
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("C:\\test.log")) )
{
   while ( ( line = reader.ReadLine() ) != null )
   {
       lines[index] = line;
       index = 1-index;
   }
}
// Last Line -1 = lines[index]
// Last line    = lines[1-index]
```