# How to read a very huge file from the end in C#?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, filestream

I have a text file of size 4.5GB, which was created by one of the experimental applications. On my system of 8GB RAM, this file cannot be opened (tried with sublime text). I just want to **read the content of this file from the end**, say 45 characters from the end, without loading the entire file in memory. How to do this ? 
The inbuilt methods like,

```
StreamReader.ReadBlock(char[] buffer,int index,int count)
```

has type *int* for index, but the index for my case is out of the range for int value. If only there was an overload with long. How to overcome this ? Thanks.

Comment: go oldschool? fopen/fseek?

Comment: [`FileStream.Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx)? Darin Dimitrov shows an example how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368857/read-from-a-file-starting-at-the-end-similar-to-tail

Comment: What encoding is the text file in? If it is UTF-8 can you guarantee that there are only single byte wide characters in the file?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain YES, since the output is from my own application, its guaranteed that the file is made up of ASCII characters only.

Comment: @birryree Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. SO didn't suggest that link while I was typing that question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Stream` has `long` properties named `Position` and `Length`. You can set the `Position` to any value you like within the range `[0, Length[`, like `fileStream.Position = fileStream.Length - 45;`.

Or, you could use the `Stream.Seek` function: `fileStream.Seek(-45, SeekOrigin.End)`.

Use the more readable one depending on the surrounding code and situation, the one that best conveys your intention.

Here's some code:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("myfile.txt"))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.ASCII))
{
    if (fileStream.Length >= 45)
        fileStream.Seek(-45, SeekOrigin.End);

    var value = streamReader.ReadToEnd(); // Last 45 chars;
}
```

This is easier since you know your file is encoded in ASCII. Otherwise, you'd have to read a bit of text from the start of the file with the reader to let it detect the encoding (if a BOM is present), and only then seek to the position you want to read from.

Comment: The problem is `StreamReader` is not derived from `Stream`. You should show how the two interact.

Comment: @Scott, I've assumed the OP already had a file stream, but you're right, some example code is appropriate here.