# How to read the last x bytes of a binary file?

Tags: c#

How can I read the last x bytes from a binary file or is there a way to determine how many bytes are in the file?

I could then at least try something like:

```
File.ReadAllBytes(file).Skip(Size-25).Take(25).ToArray();
```

Comment: have you considered looking at a `Stream`?

Comment: Of course there is. Literally the first result on a search will show it. And please don't write something like that. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Move the read pointer to the end minus x and then perform the read. You know the amount of bytes by asking the SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4368857/read-from-a-file-starting-at-the-end-similar-to-tail