# How do I read last 10 lines in a text file?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-micro-framework

I need to read last 10 lines in my file. File is about a 1MB, but I need code to be very efficient because of it will be running in a limited device.

PD: I've tested code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398378/get-last-10-lines-of-very-large-text-file-10gb-c-sharp/) post and no one is working for me.

**EDIT**
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398512/1004962) code is not working because of NETMF 4.1 does not have **GetByteCount** and **GetString**, do you know any other way to do this?

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what is not working for you? Are you getting an error message? How is the actual result different than the expected result?

Comment: Have you tried the code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp/452945#452945? Note that you'll need to say what the encoding of the file it - it makes a huge difference.

Comment: None working you need to expand that part

Comment: Could you specify what "no one is working" means? What have you tried, and what happens?

Comment: This one http://stackoverflow.com/a/398512/1004962 only return me one line and this http://stackoverflow.com/a/399841/1004962 is not returning last 10 lines and are not in right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is How I've finally solved. Anyway code is too slow so if any of you have any advice, please tell me:

```
    public static string ReadEndTokens(string filename, Int64 numberOfTokens, Encoding encoding, string tokenSeparator)
    {
        lock (typeof(SDAccess))
        {
            PersistentStorage sdPS = new PersistentStorage("SD");
            sdPS.MountFileSystem();
            string rootDirectory = VolumeInfo.GetVolumes()[0].RootDirectory;

            int sizeOfChar = 1;//The only encoding suppourted by NETMF4.1 is UTF8
            byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(tokenSeparator);


            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(rootDirectory + @"\" + filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                Int64 tokenCount = 0;
                Int64 endPosition = fs.Length / sizeOfChar;

                for (Int64 position = sizeOfChar; position < endPosition; position += sizeOfChar)
                {
                    fs.Seek(-position, SeekOrigin.End);
                    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    encoding.GetChars(buffer);
                    if (encoding.GetChars(buffer)[0].ToString() + encoding.GetChars(buffer)[1].ToString() == tokenSeparator)
                    {
                        tokenCount++;
                        if (tokenCount == numberOfTokens)
                        {
                            byte[] returnBuffer = new byte[fs.Length - fs.Position];
                            fs.Read(returnBuffer, 0, returnBuffer.Length);                          
                            sdPS.UnmountFileSystem();// Unmount file system
                            sdPS.Dispose();
                            return GetString(returnBuffer);
                        }
                    }
                }

                // handle case where number of tokens in file is less than numberOfTokens
                fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
                fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                sdPS.UnmountFileSystem();// Unmount file system
                sdPS.Dispose();
                return GetString(buffer);
            }
        }
    }

    //As GetString is not implemented in NETMF4.1 I've done this method
    public static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
    {
        string cadena = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            cadena += Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(bytes)[i].ToString();
        return cadena;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try: File.ReadLines(myFilePath); and use Linq.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx