# How to efficiently read only last line of the text file

Tags: c#, file, stream

Need to get just last line from big log file. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to read the file backwards using `ReverseLineReader`:

[How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)

Then run `.Take(1)` on it.

```
var lines = new ReverseLineReader(filename);
var last = lines.Take(1);
```

You'll want to use [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) library [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) directly rather than copying/pasting the code.

Comment: Nice! Thank you, will try it.

Comment: Strange that the library is not in Nuget..Thanks!

Comment: See my answer in the possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/33907602/4821032

Comment: I know this answer is from the past, but for anyone reading this, "You'll want to NOT use Jon Skeet's library directly" as per Jon Skeet himself, rather DO copy/paste, take what you want from the code. https://github.com/jpsingleton/ANCLAFS/issues/6

Answer (score 2):

```
    String lastline="";
    String filedata;

    // Open file to read
    var fullfiledata = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fullfiledata);

    //long offset = sr.BaseStream.Length - ((sr.BaseStream.Length * lengthWeNeed) / 100);
    // Assuming a line doesnt have more than 500 characters, else use above formula
    long offset = sr.BaseStream.Length - 500;

    //directly move the last 500th position
    sr.BaseStream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    //From there read lines, not whole file
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        filedata = sr.ReadLine();
        // Interate to see last line
        if (sr.Peek() == -1)
        {
            lastline = filedata;
        }
    }       

    return lastline;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Or you can do it two line (.Net 4 only)

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(path);
string line = lines.Last();
```

Comment: While this can do the job, it's incredibly memory inefficient (as RJFalconer notes) and also has a great deal of latency - remember that reading a file is one of the slowest things you can do in a program.  If you're only infrequently reading, this might work out, but this is _far_ from a strong, professional solution.