# C# Text File Reading ObjectDisposedException: The object was used after being disposed

Tags: c#, file, stream

I want to read the last line of a text file. I'm using a solution that's suggested here:

[How to efficiently read only last line of the text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409977/how-to-efficiently-read-only-last-line-of-the-text-file)

Using that library, I'm getting an error saying the stream is disposed. But I'm confused as I'm declaring the stream during every frame.

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\LukasRoper\\Desktop\\Test.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);


ReverseLineReader reverseLineReader = new ReverseLineReader(() => fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);

List<string> stringParts = new List<string>();
do
{
    IEnumerable<string> line = reverseLineReader.Take(1);
    string data = line.First();

    stringParts = data.Split(',').ToList();
} while (stringParts.Count != 9);
```

I should explain I'm trying to read from a file that another program is writing to at the same time and I can't amend that program as its third party software. Can anybody explain why my FileStream becomes disposed?

The Reverse File Reader is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace MiscUtil.IO
{
/// <summary>
/// Takes an encoding (defaulting to UTF-8) and a function which produces a seekable stream
/// (or a filename for convenience) and yields lines from the end of the stream backwards.
/// Only single byte encodings, and UTF-8 and Unicode, are supported. The stream
/// returned by the function must be seekable.
/// </summary>
public sealed class ReverseLineReader : IEnumerable<string>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Buffer size to use by default. Classes with internal access can specify
    /// a different buffer size - this is useful for testing.
    /// </summary>
    private const int DefaultBufferSize = 4096;

    /// <summary>
    /// Means of creating a Stream to read from.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Func<Stream> streamSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// Encoding to use when converting bytes to text
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Encoding encoding;

    /// <summary>
    /// Size of buffer (in bytes) to read each time we read from the
    /// stream. This must be at least as big as the maximum number of
    /// bytes for a single character.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly int bufferSize;

    /// <summary>
    /// Function which, when given a position within a file and a byte, states whether
    /// or not the byte represents the start of a character.
    /// </summary>
    private Func<long,byte,bool> characterStartDetector;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a LineReader from a stream source. The delegate is only
    /// called when the enumerator is fetched. UTF-8 is used to decode
    /// the stream into text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="streamSource">Data source</param>
    public ReverseLineReader(Func<Stream> streamSource)
        : this(streamSource, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a LineReader from a filename. The file is only opened
    /// (or even checked for existence) when the enumerator is fetched.
    /// UTF8 is used to decode the file into text.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">File to read from</param>
    public ReverseLineReader(string filename)
        : this(filename, Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a LineReader from a filename. The file is only opened
    /// (or even checked for existence) when the enumerator is fetched.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">File to read from</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">Encoding to use to decode the file into text</param>
    public ReverseLineReader(string filename, Encoding encoding)
        : this(() => File.OpenRead(filename), encoding)
    {
    }

        /// <summary>
    /// Creates a LineReader from a stream source. The delegate is only
    /// called when the enumerator is fetched.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="streamSource">Data source</param>
    /// <param name="encoding">Encoding to use to decode the stream into text</param>
    public ReverseLineReader(Func<Stream> streamSource, Encoding encoding)
        : this(streamSource, encoding, DefaultBufferSize)
    {
    }

    internal ReverseLineReader(Func<Stream> streamSource, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize)
    {
        this.streamSource = streamSource;
        this.encoding = encoding;
        this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
        if (encoding.IsSingleByte)
        {
            // For a single byte encoding, every byte is the start (and end) of a character
            characterStartDetector = (pos, data) => true;
        }
        else if (encoding is UnicodeEncoding)
        {
            // For UTF-16, even-numbered positions are the start of a character
            characterStartDetector = (pos, data) => (pos & 1) == 0;
        }
        else if (encoding is UTF8Encoding)
        {
            // For UTF-8, bytes with the top bit clear or the second bit set are the start of a character
            // See http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html
            characterStartDetector = (pos, data) => (data & 0x80) == 0 || (data & 0x40) != 0;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Only single byte, UTF-8 and Unicode encodings are permitted");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the enumerator reading strings backwards. If this method discovers that
    /// the returned stream is either unreadable or unseekable, a NotSupportedException is thrown.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Stream stream = streamSource();
        if (!stream.CanSeek)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unable to seek within stream");
        }
        if (!stream.CanRead)
        {
            stream.Dispose();
            throw new NotSupportedException("Unable to read within stream");
        }
        return GetEnumeratorImpl(stream);
    }

    private IEnumerator<string> GetEnumeratorImpl(Stream stream)
    {
        try
        {
            long position = stream.Length;

            if (encoding is UnicodeEncoding && (position & 1) != 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("UTF-16 encoding provided, but stream has odd length.");
            }

            // Allow up to two bytes for data from the start of the previous
            // read which didn't quite make it as full characters
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize + 2];
            char[] charBuffer = new char[encoding.GetMaxCharCount(buffer.Length)];
            int leftOverData = 0;
            String previousEnd = null;
            // TextReader doesn't return an empty string if there's line break at the end
            // of the data. Therefore we don't return an empty string if it's our *first*
            // return.
            bool firstYield = true;

            // A line-feed at the start of the previous buffer means we need to swallow
            // the carriage-return at the end of this buffer - hence this needs declaring
            // way up here!
            bool swallowCarriageReturn = false;

            while (position > 0)
            {
                int bytesToRead = Math.Min(position > int.MaxValue ? bufferSize : (int)position, bufferSize);

                position -= bytesToRead;
                stream.Position = position;
                StreamUtil.ReadExactly(stream, buffer, bytesToRead);
                // If we haven't read a full buffer, but we had bytes left
                // over from before, copy them to the end of the buffer
                if (leftOverData > 0 && bytesToRead != bufferSize)
                {
                    // Buffer.BlockCopy doesn't document its behaviour with respect
                    // to overlapping data: we *might* just have read 7 bytes instead of
                    // 8, and have two bytes to copy...
                    Array.Copy(buffer, bufferSize, buffer, bytesToRead, leftOverData);
                }
                // We've now *effectively* read this much data.
                bytesToRead += leftOverData;

                int firstCharPosition = 0;
                while (!characterStartDetector(position + firstCharPosition, buffer[firstCharPosition]))
                {
                    firstCharPosition++;
                    // Bad UTF-8 sequences could trigger this. For UTF-8 we should always
                    // see a valid character start in every 3 bytes, and if this is the start of the file
                    // so we've done a short read, we should have the character start
                    // somewhere in the usable buffer.
                    if (firstCharPosition == 3 || firstCharPosition == bytesToRead)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid UTF-8 data");
                    }
                }
                leftOverData = firstCharPosition;

                int charsRead = encoding.GetChars(buffer, firstCharPosition, bytesToRead - firstCharPosition, charBuffer, 0);
                int endExclusive = charsRead;

                for (int i = charsRead - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    char lookingAt = charBuffer[i];
                    if (swallowCarriageReturn)
                    {
                        swallowCarriageReturn = false;
                        if (lookingAt == '\r')
                        {
                            endExclusive--;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    // Anything non-line-breaking, just keep looking backwards
                    if (lookingAt != '\n' && lookingAt != '\r')
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    // End of CRLF? Swallow the preceding CR
                    if (lookingAt == '\n')
                    {
                        swallowCarriageReturn = true;
                    }
                    int start = i + 1;
                    string bufferContents = new string(charBuffer, start, endExclusive - start);
                    endExclusive = i;
                    string stringToYield = previousEnd == null ? bufferContents : bufferContents + previousEnd;
                    if (!firstYield || stringToYield.Length != 0)
                    {
                        yield return stringToYield;
                    }
                    firstYield = false;
                    previousEnd = null;
                }

                previousEnd = endExclusive == 0 ? null : (new string(charBuffer, 0, endExclusive) + previousEnd);

                // If we didn't decode the start of the array, put it at the end for next time
                if (leftOverData != 0)
                {
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, buffer, bufferSize, leftOverData);
                }
            }
            if (leftOverData != 0)
            {
                // At the start of the final buffer, we had the end of another character.
                throw new InvalidDataException("Invalid UTF-8 data at start of stream");
            }
            if (firstYield && string.IsNullOrEmpty(previousEnd))
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return previousEnd ?? "";
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

}

I do see that dispose is called on the stream, but doesn't redeclaring it fix that? That class was copied from here: [How to read a text file reversely with iterator in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452902/how-to-read-a-text-file-reversely-with-iterator-in-c-sharp)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your `finally` clause in `private IEnumerator<string> GetEnumeratorImpl(Stream stream)` is disposing your stream after you read from it. Generally you should disposing an object in the same scope or class you create it in.

In this case, remove all disposes in `ReverseLineReader` and wrap your original code in a using:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(...))
{
   ...
   do
   {
       ...
   } while(...);
}
```