# Writing to file asynchronously results in incorrect number of lines and incorrect contents

Tags: .net, asynchronous, logging

I have a small logger class that just contains some static helper methods for easily writing to a log file. I wanted to test how robust it was, so I attempted to run it asynchronously 100 times at once.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Diagnostics_AsyncWritePass()
{
    int linesToWrite = 100;
    String logMsg = "Async test log ";
    List<Task> asyncTaskList = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < linesToWrite; i++)
    {
        Task task = new Task(() => Logger.Info(logMsg + i));
        asyncTaskList.Add(task);
        task.Start();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(asyncTaskList.ToArray());

    List<String> lines = GetLastLogLines(linesToWrite);

    foreach (String line in lines)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(line.Contains(logMsg));
    }
}
```

The actual logging (inside the `Logger.Info` method) is performed using:

```
File.AppendAllText(LogPath, logMsg + Environment.NewLine);
```

The `GetLastLogLines` method is:

```
private List<String> GetLastLogLines(int numLines)
{
    List<String> lines = File.ReadLines(Logger.LogPath)
        .Reverse()
        .Take(numLines)
        .ToList();
    return lines;
}
```

However, I have two issues with this.

- The first is that it is not writing 100 lines, it is writing around 90.
- The second is that every line is `Async test log 100` - the number does not increment every line. I'm guessing that the `i` counter is being passed by reference, not by value.

Why might these problems occur?

**EDIT:**
The incorrect number of lines issue was solved by replacing the contents of `GetLastLogLines`. Previously, it was using `File.ReadLines` then using LINQ to take only x number of lines. Instead, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15867819/2000012) and it returned the correct number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second problem is standard issue when a lambda expression captures an iteration variable.

Make the following change.

```
for (int i = 0; i < linesToWrite; i++)
{
    var t = i;
    Task task = new Task(() => Logger.Info(logMsg + t));
    asyncTaskList.Add(task);
    task.Start();
}
```

Can you show us what `GetLastLogLines()` does?