# Read Last 2 Lines Of Text File VB.Net Win Forms

Tags: vb.net

From a button click I am trying to read a text file and then output just the last 2 lines into a Label. The data in the text file changes regular but the format is always the same.

**This is an example of what is in the text file.**

1393
00:23:12,000 --> 00:23:13,000
2020/08/12 12:43:47
+DMR  DCC=4
Slot 1  TG=9003  RID=69

The last 2 lines is what I am interested in getting which in the above example would be
+DMR  DCC=4
Slot 1  TG=9003  RID=69
This is what I have so far which seems to work but I just feel its a bit messy and was wondering if anyone had any other suggestions.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Label1.text= ReadLog()

End Sub

Public Function ReadLog() As String
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\MyApp\log.txt")
    If lines.Length <= 4 Then Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines)
    Dim lines4(3) As String
    Array.Copy(lines, lines.Length - 3, lines4, 0, 3)
    Return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines4)
End Function
```

Comment: This would probably be better on the Code Review site.  (I'd flag it to be moved, but Code Review isn't one of the options.)

Comment: Here's a similar c# question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15867758/read-only-given-last-x-lines-in-txt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you want the last two lines but the code you have indicates that you want the last four lines. Regardless, set `lineCount` to the appropriate value in the code below.

```vb
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim lastLines = lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Length - lineCount))
Dim text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, lastLines)
```

Comment: Thank you. Condensing this down to just 3 lines of code has made it much more readable. Dim lastLines = lines.Skip(Math.Max(0, lines.Length - lineCount)) is something that I would never have figured out.