# Read very big text file with visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I need some advice on a project I'm working on. I thought I'd use Visual Basic for this, mainly because I need a nice looking GUI for this code.

I want to read the last ~10000 lines in a very big text file. The text file can be 20GB in size, so I need some way of reading the lines from the end, like "tail -f 1000" (if I remember correctly).

I tried using streamreader on a much smaller file (12MB), and it takes a very long time (several minutes) to read the whole file.

Do I have any options other than abandoning VB and resort to python (that reads the 12MB file in a about a second)

Tobbe

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get last 10 lines of very large text file > 10GB c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398378/get-last-10-lines-of-very-large-text-file-10gb-c-sharp)

Comment: FYI tail is a unix command...

Comment: Hi. Yes I know tail is a unix command. I use it to check the last section of these big files, but now I need to actually use those lines in code.